# Coding a hamburger menu with JS, CSS & HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've created a menu that allows you to display the list when clicking on the menu icon. I wonder whether this can be improved somehow - can anyone help improve this?

Also, initially I created it with the event passed into the script to prevent it from scrolling to the top when clicking on the link. I then changed it to an ES6 function - does it not need the event passed in and calling `e.preventDefault()`?

Thank you. The code is as follows:

```js
  const cont = document.querySelector('.cont');
  const hamburger = document.querySelector('#hamburger');
  
  // const toggleMenu = (e) => {
  //   e.preventDefault();
  //   cont.classList.toggle('open');
  // }
  const toggleDisplay = () => cont.classList.toggle('open');
  
  hamburger.addEventListener('click', toggleDisplay);
```

```css
.cont {
  position: relative;
}
a {
  font-size: 3em;
}
a:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
a::after {
  content: '\002b';
}
.open a::after {
  content: '\00d7';
  color: red;
}
.open ul {
  display: flex;
}
ul {
  all: unset;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background: #0ff;
  padding: .5em;
  min-width: 100px;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
}
li {
  all: unset;
  width: 100%;
}
li:not(:first-child) {
  margin-top: .5em;
  padding-top: .5em;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class='cont'>
  <a id='hamburger'></a>
  <ul>
    <li>First</li>
    <li>Second</li>
    <li>Third</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here are a few suggestions:

- '.cont' is a bit vague - I suppose it means container but try to avoid meaningless abbreviations
- Be careful with `all: unset`. It might have unexpected consequences cross-browser.
- I would stick to `rem` for margin/paddings and only use `em` for fontsizes. There is a lot of articles explaining the  difference if you perform a simple google search
- You could make it behave a little more smoothly if you had a CSS transition
- Instead of a wrapping div this could potentially be a `nav` element if it is part of some navigation. Always try to use semantically correct tags
- I don't think you want an `a` tag here as you are not linking to anything. Maybe a button would be better?

As for your question both of your functions are ES6 functions (`fat-arrow functions`).

In the example you commented out you are using `explicit return` while you are using `implicit return` in the latter.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. A few questions:
1. What side-effects could `all: unset` have?
2. I read that the opposite is true, and that `em` is perfect for padding/margin as it's based on the inherited font size, and `rem` is ok for font sizes - research seemed subjective but generally agreeable on `em` for margins/padding
3. What's wrong with the `a` tag? It's good for accessibility as it's selectable when pressing tab (although so are buttons)
4. True, but does it actually need `e.preventDefault()`?

Comment: 1. You can check compatibility on "caniuse.com".. It might also impact accessibility on some fields. In your case I guess you are really just trying to reset the list-style-type. 2. `em` is relative to the **nearest parent** while `rem` is to the root font-size. That's why padding/margins with `em` could lead to more inconsistent designs imo. Not sure where you found that consensus :). 3. It's semantically incorrect. You should use `a` tags for links. You can get the same accessibility with a button. 4. No there is no default action to prevent if you don't have any href value.

Comment: Use tags that best convey intent - ditto. I'd have upvoted even if that was the only nugget in this answer.